# Change all the Excel cells Type to Text/General using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to upload one excel file containing multiple value types and values with $ symbol etc. My requirement is to convert all the excel cell type to Text/General after uploading the excel file.
Thanks in Advance,
Wilson.

Answer (score 2):

```
Worksheet ws;

Range oRng;
```

Load your Workseet in the ws 
Now Select the Range of cells for which the formatting is to be done.

for eg

```
oRng = ws.get_Range(StartCol + StartRow, EndCol + EndRow);

Now just set oRng.NumberFormat `= "@";`
```